# Regular parametrised curve and its length

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Consider the function $r : [1/4, 3/4] → \Reals^2$ defined as $r(t) = (\sqrt{t}, \sqrt{1−t})$.  I need to determine whether it is regular and to compute its length. I am given a hint: Computing the length requires the use of the inverse function of the sin, the
arcsin.

Well I know that a curve is regular if $r'(t)\neq 0$ $\forall t$ and also the length equals $\int^a_b \|r'(t)\|\, dt$.  However I don't know what $t$ to plug in to $r$ in order to show that it is regular and also I cannot find the reason why to use sin and arcsin for the length!

$$
r'(t) = \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}, \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{1-t}}\right),
\quad\text{and so}\quad
\|r'(t)\| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{1-t}}\right)^2}.
$$

Comment: You're not using the right definition of 'regular'.

Comment: which definition do I have to use?

Comment: The one I know asks for $r'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in \text{dom}(r)$.

Comment: The definition that I am given says what I mentioned above for all t

Comment: A quick google search suggests that what I said is a standard definition. There's probably a typo on your notes.

Comment: okay, what about the length?

Comment: Well, find $r'$ and then it's norm. Put that work in your question and then I'll take a look. I'm too old to differentiate.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: You're missing a minus sign in derivative of the second coordinate. You can also simplify the norm of the derivative a lot. Regarding its regularity, according to the standard definition, can you now see why it is regular?

Comment: Yes but since the norm can simplified a lot why do I have to use sin and arcsin in order to find the length?

Comment: Simplify the algebra and try to do the integral. You'll need to complete the square ...

Comment: @user189013: I added curly braces around sqrt arguments for legibility, and edited the definition of regularity in your question (changing "$r(t) \neq 0$" to "$r'(t) \neq 0$").

Comment: If I were you, I would completely re-parameterize the entire curve, using the obvious observation that $x^2(t)+y^2(t)=1$.